# find and remove element from array (solidity)

Tags: solidity

I've tackled a task: find a specific address in a sheet, move it to the end of the sheet, and remove it via a function pop! here is the code:

```
function removeAccount(address _account) external{
        uint counter = arrayOfAccounts.length;
        uint index;
        for(uint i; i < counter; i++) {
            if(arrayOfAccounts[i] == _account){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        for(uint i = index; i < counter-1; i++){
                arrayOfAccounts[i] = arrayOfAccounts[i + 1];
            }
            arrayOfAccounts.pop();
        }
    }
        }
    }
```

> > transact to Wote.removeAccount errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont care about addresses order

```
function removeAccount(address _account) external {
    if(arrayOfAccounts.length == 1) {
        arrayOfAccounts.pop();
    }
    else if(arrayOfAccounts[arrayOfAccounts.length - 1] == _account) {
        arrayOfAccounts.pop();
    }
    else {
        for (uint i = 0; i < arrayOfAccounts.length - 1; i++) {
            if(_account == arrayOfAccounts[i]) {
                arrayOfAccounts[i] = arrayOfAccounts[arrayOfAccounts.length - 1];
                arrayOfAccounts.pop();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If order matters

```
function removeAccount(address _account) external{
        uint counter = arrayOfAccounts.length;
        for(uint i; i < counter; i++) {
            if(arrayOfAccounts[i] == _account){
                for(uint j = i; j < counter-1; j++){
                    arrayOfAccounts[j] = arrayOfAccounts[j + 1];
                }
                arrayOfAccounts.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Else if order doesn't matter

```
function removeAccount(address _account) external{
    uint numAccounts = arrayOfAccounts.length;
    for(uint i = 0; i < numAccounts; i++) {
        if(arrayOfAccounts[i] == _account){    // if _account is in the array
            arrayOfAccounts[i] = arrayOfAccounts[numAccounts - 1];    // move the last account to _account's index
            arrayOfAccounts.pop();    // remove the last account
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is just simple.
You used the second `for` loop inside the first `for` loop.
And also please initialize the `index` with `counter`;

```
uint256 index = counter;
```

And pop only when `index` is less than `counter`